# Smarty foreach index value issue

Tags: smarty

In smarty foreach loop,{$smarty.foreach.foo.iteration} is working fine,but {$smarty.foreach.foo.index} is not working. I couldn't figure out the issue.

Please any one help me!!!

Example:

code:

```
{foreach name=navLoop from=$links_res_cat_detailsObj item="links_res"}
{$smarty.foreach.navLoop.iteration}
{/if}
```

output:123
but when i am trying to printout the index value, i am geting nothing
Example

code:

```
{foreach name=navLoop from=$links_res_cat_detailsObj item="links_res"}
{$smarty.foreach.navLoop.index}
{/if}
```

output:

Comment: Can you show us an example of the code you are using and the error messages/output that you get?

Comment: Thanks for reply!!

I got the following output


code:

{foreach name=navLoop from=$links_res_cat_detailsObj item="links_res"}
{$smarty.foreach.navLoop.iteration}
{/if}

output: 123


but when i am trying to printout the index value, i am geting nothing
Example

code:

{foreach name=navLoop from=$links_res_cat_detailsObj item="links_res"}
{$smarty.foreach.navLoop.index}
{/if}

output:

Comment: I'd edit your original question and put the code/output in there - will make it much easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

This is really strange. It looks like you are using it correctly (see [the manual](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.index))
I've compiled a test for you, and this works fine. Could it be some typo, or a problem in the data?

```
    <ul>
    {foreach item=item from=$myVar name=test}
        <li>{$smarty.foreach.test.iteration} - {$smarty.foreach.test.index}</li>
    {/foreach}
    </ul>
```

The only thing strange about your code is the `"` around your item, but that could not be the problem, could it? I'd run it with above thest (so both the iteration and the index), to make sure one works and the other doesn't... Because that's just weird :)

Answer (score 0):

The smarty template system implemented in phpfox uses custom functionality and not everything is implemented. Though you should try using the $phpfox. instead of $smarty.

The following will work (tested on v3.6):

```
{foreach item=item from=$myVar name=test}
    <li>{$phpfox.foreach.test.iteration} - {$phpfox.foreach.test.index}</li>
{/foreach}
```